# Gmail App / Android HTML e-mail issue

Tags: android, email, gmail

Really very desperate to solve this issue and hoping someone could help! I have an adaptive e-mail set up which works fine everywhere except Gmail app / Android. Very faint lines appear horizontally between the tables and I can't seem to get rid of them. Does anyone have a solution? Would be most appreciated. Slimmed down version of the code below. (Full version has more tables thats all).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1909/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">


        body[yahoo] .contact a {
            color: #000;
        }
        body[yahoo] .footer a {
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }



    </style>

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="background: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0; Margin: 0; min-width: 100%;">

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000;"><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <table class="wrap" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; Margin: 0; font-size: 0; "><tr><td>





        <!--Block 1-->
        <table class="hero-img" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img src="NCG-footer1.jpg" style="display: block; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>






        <!--Block 2-->
        <table class="hero-img" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><a href="unsubscribe" style="border: 0;"><img src="NCG-footer2.jpg" style="display: block; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>




        <!--Block 3-->
        <table class="pre-header" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#00551f" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; background: #00551f; color: #ffffff; font-size: 10px; Margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100%" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center">Trouble viewing this email. Please <a href="linkhere" style="color: #ffffff;">click here</a> to view it online. </td>
            </tr>
        </table>









        <!--Block 4-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#00551f" height="50px" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>






</body>
</html>
```